# x+x^1.0 Won't Simplify Using sympy

Tags: sympy

For example:

```
eqn = N('1.00*x +1.00*x**1.0')
```

This returns:

```
1.0*x + 1.0*x**1.0
```

I think what I need to do is convert floats that are equivalent to  integers into integers because this:

```
eqn = N('1.00*x+1.00*x**1')
```

Returns:

```
2.0*x
```

Which is what I want.

I tried this, but it seem to do anything:

```
eqn = eqn.replace(lambda x: x.is_integer, lambda x: int(x))
```

I think this doesn't work because sympy's is_integer only works for integers, not floats that are equivalent to integers.

Comment: On sympy master the original example gives `2.0*x`

Comment: Same with sympy 1.5. Which version are you using?

Comment: Oops, 1.1! Good catch, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observations about the new behavior not withstanding, you can make the change with

```
>>> eqn.xreplace({k: int(k) for k in eqn.atoms(Float) if k == int(k)})
2*x
```

The `replace` will not act on things for which `old == new`.